# How to substitute one column with another or implement data-obfuscation depending on user name

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, obfuscation

I have a report which contains Personal Identification Information, which should not be visible to anyone who can use the report. This includes, but is not limited to email adresses.
This is not a RLS issue - all the visuals need to be visible, just some of them should show those PII only to users with granted access. RLS would result with some visuals simply showing error.

So what I came up is data obfuscation - the query to SnowFlake can encrypt the data before sending it back to PBI (the mode is DirectQuery - import has been ruled out for security reason), but it seems I can't use parameter for that query in PBI (where only one of consequence is USERPRINCIPALNAME() function), because it's explicitly blocked from working outside RLS or measure.

Similarly, there is no way to build a measure that would substitute one column for another as this method requires aggregation...

Calculated column does not work for same reason as parameterized query (use of USERPRINCIPALNAME() function is explicitly forbidden in this way), but even then it would require to convert to import. As mentioned - direct query is required.

I am trying to do it for a few weeks now and it seems it's not possible. Is there any way to do it short of creating two separate reports?

PS - I attempted to add Tag "data-obfuscation", which should be created - this is one of the method of dealing with GDPR requirements - buuut not enough rep. So used the other one.

Comment: Have you checked Dynamic Data Masking?

Comment: @Limonka - Dynamic Data Masking was rejected, as it requires every report user to be also a Snowflake user and have assigned masking role, which in turns requires every report user to use his own SnowFlake credentials and have default role set, which is out of the question. In addition, this report used two data sources that are on two different spokes, which means twice the users to maintain. There must be an easier way.

Comment: Can you clarify if this is the Snowflake user name or the PBI user name? It would appear to be the PBI user name since Snowflake does not have a built-in function called USERPRINCIPALNAME.

Comment: @GregPavlik Edited for clarity, but to be as clear as possible: yes, it's about PBI function mostly. If I try to use it in parameter and then insert that parameter in the query that PBI will then send to SnowFlake, then the parameter will have contain string 'USERPRINCIPALNAME()'